# Export Specific User data without plugin

Tags: query, users, export

I need to export a list of site users to a csv/xlsx file. I am creating an admin page with a download button which should run the export function.

I need to export the following data from wp_users:

- ID
- user_email
- user_registered

I need to export the following data from wp_usermeta:

- first_name
- last_name
- institution (this is a custom meta field)

How can I go about exporting this on the click of a button? I have the admin page and button setup but not sure on the correct query to get the data and put it into a csv

Comment: can you tell what you have tried so far?

Comment: do you need both tables relationally merged?